# Gtk widget shows up with delay

Tags: python, gtk

Using python3 and gi.repository, I want to have a Gtk.HeaderBar with a Gtk.Button that is replaced by a Gtk.Spinner as soon as you click on it. After a calculation the button should appear again.

Here is an example of how I think it should work but the Gtk.Spinner only shows up **after** the calculation (in this example sleep) for a very short time. How can I achieve that the spinner shows up for the whole calculation (or sleep)?

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
import time

class window:
    def __init__(self):
        self.w = Gtk.Window()
        self.button = Gtk.Button('x')
        self.button.connect('clicked', self.on_button_clicked)
        self.spinner = Gtk.Spinner()
        self.hb = Gtk.HeaderBar()
        self.hb.props.show_close_button = True
        self.hb.pack_start(self.button)
        self.w.set_titlebar(self.hb)
        self.w.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
        self.w.show_all()

    def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
        self.button.hide()
        self.hb.pack_start(self.spinner)
        self.spinner.show()
        self.spinner.start()
        time.sleep(5)
        self.spinner.stop()
        self.hb.remove(self.spinner)
        self.button.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = window()
    Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GTK+ is an event driven system where the mainloop should be left free to update the UI and everything that takes time (like reading from a file, making a network connection, long calculations) should happen asynchronously.

In your case this would look something like this:

```
def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
    self.button.hide()
    self.spinner.show()
    self.spinner.start()
    GLib.timeout_add_seconds (5, self.processing_finished)

def processing_finished(self):
    self.spinner.stop()
    self.spinner.hide()
    self.button.show()
```

Note that I removed the pack and remove calls: do those in `__init__()`. You'll want `from gi.repository import GLib` in there as well.

This way the main loop is free to update the UI as often as it wants. If you really want to use a blocking call like sleep(), then you'll need to do that in another thread, but my suggestion is to use libraries that are asychronous like that `timeout_add_seconds()` call.

Comment: So I have to use GLib.spawn_async to run a function asynchronously?

Comment: @user3749818 No, spawn_async is for launching separate processes (it is an asynchronous function though). What I mean is that you should use libraries that provide an asynchronous, event-driven API -- practically all of GNOME libraries are like that: you can always avoid blocking calls when using them. If you absolutely need to use an API that has blocking calls, then you should use threads. There are several ways to do that. With a modern GLib I'd probably try a GTask with `g_task_run_in_thread ()`.

Comment: Where is GTask located? Is it part of gi.repository?

Comment: @user3749818 oh sorry, that is indeed quite a un-googleable term... [GTask](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GTask.html) is in Gio which is developed as part of GLib but is a separate library: it should be "Gio" in gi.repository. Sorry I can't help with the python syntax though. That said, I still repeat the advice: if you can, avoid threads and use libraries that handle the complexity for you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is time.sleep(): it is a blocking function.

```
def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
    self.button.hide()
    self.hb.pack_start(self.spinner)
    self.spinner.show()
    self.spinner.start()
    t = time.time()
    while time.time() - t < 5:
        Gtk.main_iteration()
    self.spinner.stop()
    self.hb.remove(self.spinner)
    self.button.show()
```

I think that's what you expect.

Edit: You may put a time.sleep(.1) inside while loop, for cpu saving, but don't forget Gtk.main_iteration(): that is the function that exit from while loop to main loop (show spinner, progress bar and so on).

Comment: I have two questions to that. Firstly, I don't really know anything about blocking functions but why does it seem to be executed before the spinner is shown? Secondly, is this also possible using threads? (Does not make sense with sleep but with calculations)

Comment: @user3749818 you don't give the main loop any possibility to show the spinner during the five seconds -- that's what blocking means. I don't think manually pumping the main loop like cox does is a good solution for most cases, see my answer for the "normal GTK solution". Threads are possible but note that GTK is not thread-safe: most gtk-functions can only be called from the main thread. This means worker threads are much more work than using sane libraries that provide an asynchronous API.

Comment: Obviously, @jku solution is more practical, since usualy you invoke a function. As about threads, stay away! Almost any UI try to protect against them: imagine that a thread could read password/text from entry - how hard will be to make a independent script that do this? The OS, not the UI knows what process belong to who. The solution is to made in threads only work that could wait to join() and be used by main thread - so, functions or threads, Gtk don't care as long as only main threads do things.