# GTK3 and Python : why is set_property delayed?

Tags: python, gtk3

This script does not work as i expect :

```
import gi
import time
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class GridWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="hi")

        def fnButton1(self):
            button1.set_property("label", "TEST")
            print("hello")
            time.sleep(3)
            print("you")

        grid = Gtk.Grid()

        button1 = Gtk.Button(label="Button 1")
        button1.connect("clicked", fnButton1)
        button2 = Gtk.Button(label="Button 2")

        grid.add(button1)
        grid.attach(button2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.add(grid)

win = GridWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

When clicking button1, its label is NOT changed, but "hello" is printed. This only happens until the 3 seconds have past : the label becomes "TEST" and "you" is printed. It seems the property change is happening when the function fnButton1() is finished, not before that .. why? And how can solve this?

I just want to be able to change some widget properties at the beginning of some function, which starts with a button click. This would be normal while programming, is it not? Why does GTK3 (with Python) behave differently?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gtk widget shows up with delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24272293/gtk-widget-shows-up-with-delay)

Answer (score 1):

```
    def fnButton1(self):
        button1.set_property("label", "TEST")
        print("hello")
        time.sleep(3)
        print("you")
```

`set_property` creates drawing commands which are queued into the background process, and will execute when Gtk's event loop 'has time' to do it's iterations. The sleep command effectively blocks the event loop from executing for 3 seconds. The print command however does execute immediately. You can see that, when moving another window over the existing one during that period, the window's contents probably won't update either.

If you really need the `sleep` you should look for one of the several ways to delay without blocking the event loop (something like add_timeout from GLib, for example)

Generally, using `sleep` or any function which blocks the event loop is a bad idea in an event-driven system such as most graphic window system.